# Smoothing only a part of a Curve

Tags: curve, smoothing

What functions/commands can I use to smooth only a part of my curve? Lets say I have data from x= 0 to x= 500 on the x-axis with corresponding y points. I would like to smooth only data between x= 200 to x= 400, and the rest to be the original data itself. So that sharp edges between x= 0 and x= 200 remains, and then between x= 200 to 400, I get a smooth curve part, and then beyond x= 400 it retains the original shape. There was nothing I could find that would let me smoothen only a part of my curve.

Could someone please help me on this one?

Best regards, 
Anirudh

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to specify which language you are using to code? 
[This page](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2012/12/07/resampling-smoothing-and-interest-points-of-curves-via-css-in-opencv-w-code/) contains some pointers. Also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17523240/algorithm-to-smooth-curve?rq=1).